# .htaccess non-www to www rule seems to work but the URL isn't changing in the address bar

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, no-www

On a joomla site, apache, shared hosting, I'm using next .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that the browser's address bar text does not change from example.com to www.example.com. It seems the redirect actually works because all the links on the pages are changed to www. And after clicking on any link from there it always continues to have www added. The problem is the first page (no matter which one) that is loaded using browser's address bar - like example.com or example.com/random-page.

Solved. The redirect actually works.

Comment: Are you using chrome? Have you checked in other browsers?

Comment: Its the same on both ff and chrome.

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine On` set?

Comment: Yes, i have it up in the htacces. I just noticed that inside jommla back-end it never redirects me to www. Could it be from Folowsymlinks? Few weeks ago when i tried to enable "Options +FollowSymLinks" in htacces got 500 error.

Comment: Got it, my retarded host edited the file after me 0.o Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's the same code I use so I don't think there's anything wrong with that. Maybe the browsers are caching the URL for whatever reason. But it might be another idea to check out http://wwwizer.com (top banner) where you set your naked A-record to that IP, then your A-record for `www` to your own IP. That eliminates any need for `.htaccess` rules.

Comment: Yes this code is working correctly. The issue was that my hosting provider had some issues with Cpanel and i was unable to get to my .htaccess file meanwhile. And during that time they overwrote my .htaccess file by mistake.

Comment: @SnakeByte - I'm sorry to hear that, but glad you have it working now.